# How to have C# use a font based on css/svg font-family string?

Tags: c#, css, c#-4.0, svg, font-family

In Microsoft's SVG Rendering Engine for C#, the font-family attribute is defined as follows:

```
[SvgAttribute("font-family")]
public virtual Font FontFamily
{
    get { return this._font; }
    set { this._font = value; this.IsPathDirty = true; }
}
```

However, this only works with something such as

```
<text style='font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode";font-size:12px;'>
```

When multiple font-families, such as

```
<text style='font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;'>
```

are specified, it just resorts to the default font (Times New Roman).

How can modify the attribute FontFamily to use the first font specified, if it exists, or the succeeding fonts, if they exist?

Answer (score -1):

Don't surround the font family types individually, enclose them as a single grouping.

```
<text style='font-family:"Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans Unicode, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica";font-size:12px;'>
```

Comment: The font-family specification requires that each font be wrapped in double quotes individually if there are multiple fallback fonts to use.

Comment: @d_r_w I believe it's actually if white space exist, not if multiple fonts are used. Not certain what the OP is using, XAML, C# code behind, straight CSS file; the above would work for XAML/C#.